# Visual Studio Intellisense for Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, backbone.js, intellisense

Is there a `-vsdoc.js` file for Backbone.js? If not, is there a feasible work-around method for intellisense with the Backbone.js javascript library?

Comment: Feasible work-around = make your own :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is vsdoc. Couldn't find it in nuget and some searching didn't bring it up.

An alternative might be to reference the non-minified version the same way you reference the vsdoc file. This may you function list and maybe parameter names.

If you have some good JS tool (many of them in Extensions Manager), or you have Resharper 6.0, you may be able to go to the definition of the function or so and read the comments in there (the non-minified version has comments, but not in vsdoc format).

**Update:**

Some common reference code, to enable intellisense but not reference the file, assuming you use the nuget package.
http://nuget.org/packages/Backbone.js

- Reference in Razor file (.cshtml)

  ```
  @if (false) { <script src="/Scripts/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script> }
  ```
- Reference in Webforms View Engine (.aspx, .ascx, .master):

  ```
  <% if(false) { %>
  <script src="/Scripts/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <% } %>
  ```
- Reference in JavaScript file (.js)

  ```
  /// <reference path="/Scripts/backbone.js" />
  ```

Answer (score 7):

Adding a `<reference />` to any unminified `.js` file will give you autocomplete of properties, functions and parameter names. You won't get pretty descriptions, but it's still a time/typing saver.

```
/// <reference path="http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/backbone.js" />
```